# баг vk sdk c передачей String

Tags: android, vkontakte-api

Есть запрос

```
String s = "qwerty";
VKParameters p = new VKParameters();
p.put(VKApiConst.OWNER_ID,-119852848);
p.put(VKApiConst.POST_ID,4);
p.put(VKApiConst.TEXT,s);
p.put(VKApiConst.SORT,"desc");
p.put(VKApiConst.COUNT,20);
VKRequest r = VKApi.wall().addComment(p);
```

Приходит ошибка 100, что не передан параметр text
но, если сделать так

```
p.put(VKApiConst.TEXT,"qwerty");
```

коментарий успешно добавляется. 
Почему просто текст в кавычках добавляется, а String переменная нет?

Comment: А если использовать getString(s), то все будет нормально?

Comment: и как его использовать?

Comment: а объявление переменной "String s = "qwerty";" - это точно правильно? И вызов ее через просто s.  Я бегло просмотрел доку, но не нашел ничего такого.

Comment: а что вы предлагаете? String s = new Srting(); s = "qwerty";

Comment: В иссуях vk api на github пробовали спрашивать?

Comment: А у вас именно такой участок кода? Если нет, добавьте свой кусок сюда

Comment: Конечно мне не нужно добавлять qwerty и String берётся из EditText. Но не работает именно такой код.

Comment: @antonin14d EditText.getText().toString() ? проверяете на null  или пустую строку? может не тот эдит текст, или пустую строку шлете?

Answer (score 4):

Не имеет ни какой разницы, что вы выполните:

```
p.put(VKApiConst.TEXT, s);
```

Что вы выполните:

```
p.put(VKApiConst.TEXT, "qwerty");

В VKsdk  VKParameters = Map<String, Object>.
```

По сути, что ввести хардкод `"qwerty"` , что `String s = "qwerty"` в памяти это объект типа String.

Ищите ошибку в коде.

Comment: Где в коде? Я привёл максимально абстрактный кусок, что бы продемонстрировать проблему. Или вы имели ввиду код vk sdk?

Comment: В Вашем коде, разумеется. Добавьте дословное описание ошибки, прям. как приходит от сервера.

Answer (score 4):

Создал минимальное тестовое приложение с авторизацией и кнопкой отправления комментария - все работает.

Также хочу заметить, что для метода [`addComment`](https://vk.com/dev/wall.addComment) не требуются параметры `sort` и `count`.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "VKApiDemo";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        VKSdk.login(this, VKScope.WALL);

        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String s = "qwerty";

                VKParameters p = new VKParameters();
                p.put(VKApiConst.OWNER_ID, -42536065);
                p.put(VKApiConst.POST_ID, 2454);
                p.put("text", "some text from app");
//                p.put(VKApiConst.SORT, "desc");
//                p.put(VKApiConst.COUNT, 20);

                VKRequest r = VKApi.wall().addComment(p);
                r.executeWithListener(new VKRequest.VKRequestListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(VKResponse response) {
                        super.onComplete(response);
                        Log.e(TAG, "onComplete: response is" + response.json.toString());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(VKError error) {
                        super.onError(error);
                        Log.e(TAG, "onError: " + error.toString());

                    }
                });    
            }
        });
    }
}
```

---

Используемая версия библиотеки vk sdk android:
`com.vk:androidsdk:1.6.7`

Comment: А библиотеку вы подключали проектом ? И не видно, что бы вы передавали String s

Comment: @user186301 нет, подключал как зависимость. Исходники не выкачивал, не занимался их компиляцией и подключением к основному проекту.

Comment: Можете привести код подключения зависимости. Ну compile...

Comment: @user186301 в ответ добавил версию библиотеки. Передавать в виде объекта типа `String` тоже пробовал, работают оба способа

Answer (score 0):

Не вижу TEXT [в списке полей VKApiConst](http://vkcom.github.io/vk-android-sdk/com/vk/sdk/api/VKApiConst.html). Предлагаю попробовать

```
p.put(VKApiConst.MESSAGE,s);
```

Comment: Попробовал, не помогает. А константу TEXT я сам вставил. public static final String TEXT = "text";
Я так делал и с другими константами, которых нет, всегда работало. Так что проблема не в этом

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте вот так

```
p.put(VKApiConst.TEXT,""+s);
```

либо поэкспериментируйте с кодировкой как-то так

```
// Данные в кодировке КОИ-8
byte[] koi8Data = ...;
// Преобразуем из КОИ-8 в Unicode
String string = new String(koi8Data,"KOI8_R");
// Преобразуем из Unicode в Windows-1251
byte[] winData = string.getBytes("Cp1251");
```

Answer (score -4):

Все верно, вам и будет приходить ошибка 100 т.к. вы используете объект.

```
s.toString()
```

используйте

или

```
String.valueOf(s);
```

Comment: Пробовал, не помогает